# The frame source device is not connected in Safari browser for futronic FS80 device

Tags: macos, safari, applet, fingerprint

I am using an Applet for capturing the fingerprints from the device fs80 to my database in my web application which is developed in Java. Which should be able to work on both windows and Mac operating systems.

The application works fine on windows operating system for capturing the fingerprints on any browser, But on Mac operating system it works on Firefox but not on Safari browser. Before it used to work fine on Safari browser also but now from past 2 to 3 months it is not working.

It Shows the message **The frame source device is not connected**.

I posted the question on Apple forum also. But the answers didn't work for me.

Please help its an production issue. The Client is only depended on Safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry to say that to you that Safari browser have stopped the fs80 driver support, Due to some of the security reasons.

The other Browsers like Firefox will be supporting.
Thank u.

I think this helps to find u another solution on that.